# Azure devOps YAML - only root level Terraform files are download

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I have Terraform files in Git-Hub with the following structure...

[image]

I have a Azure devOps Build pipeline (yaml file) connected to a Git-Hub repo where the Terraform files are located. This is part of the pipeline.

```
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    enabled: true
    displayName: 'Terraform : INIT'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      commandOptions: '-get=true'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)'
      backendServiceArm: 'spDeployment_ISL-LDS-Test'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(statefile-rg-name)'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(statefile-sa-name)'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(statefile-container-name)'
      backendAzureRmKey: '$(statefile-container-name)/$(statefile-name)'
  
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    enabled: true
    displayName: 'Terraform : VALIDATE'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'validate'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)'
      commandOptions: 
  
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    enabled: true
    displayName: 'Terraform : PLAN'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)'
      commandOptions: '-lock=false -out=plan.out -var "env=$(env)" -var "prefix=$(application-code-prefix)" -var "agentVmIpAddress=[\"$(ipaddressVar)\"]" -var "vnet_address_space=$(vnet-cidr)"'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'spDeployment_ISL-LDS-Test'
```

The top level Terraform files get downloaded and stored under "artifacts" however I also need the sub-modules to be downloaded.

[image]
I did internet search that suggested adding 'commandOptions: '-get=true' to the call to Terraform INIT but this did not work...

There also a task step to copy the Terraform files download to the Azure managed VM - copy the files to the Azure devOps artifacts location.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
    enabled: true
    displayName: 'Copy Terraform Files to: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/release/$(env)'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/$(env)
      Contents: '*.tf*'
      TargetFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/release/$(env)
```

Any suggestions on how to download any Terraform sub-modules reference in the main.tf file?

I have noticed there is a 'built in' task that runs at the beginning of the pipeline that seems to stop check-out of sub-modules...

##[debug]Fetch git repository at: /home/vsts/work/1/s remote: origin.
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --no-tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin

Comment: Use a glob pattern in your `CopyFiles` task, i.e. `'**/*.tf*'`

Comment: Thank you Daniel Mann your answer was correct. The other Terraform modules are being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use a glob pattern in your `CopyFiles` task, i.e. `'**/*.tf*'`